# Ask for JSON API WITH AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

how i can use this json ?

i use json first that fine but i use json two not working,

```
[
    {
        "name": "bryan",
        "class": "12",
        "like": "game",
        "sport": "football"
    }
]
```

that code is oke but code two not working on me if i used javascript sorry i beginner for try json api

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
        "name": "bryan",
        "class": "12",
        "like": "game",
        "sport": "football"
        }
    }
]
```

and i callback with this javascript for fist code

```
const Url='datajson.json';
$.ajax({
  url: Url,
  type:"GET",
  success: function(result){
   $('.name').html(result[0].name);
   $('.class').html(result[0].class);
   $('.like').html(result[0].like);
   $('.sport').html(result[0].sport);
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

get it to attribute arr

```
const Url='datajson.json';
$.ajax({
  url: Url,
  type:"GET",
  success: function(result){

   $('.name').html(result[0].attributes.name);
   $('.class').html(result[0].attributes.class);
   $('.like').html(result[0].attributes.like);
   $('.sport').html(result[0].attributes.sport);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because the second json have the properties you need in the **attributes** properti, in this case, your success function need to be something like:

```js
function(result){
   $('.name').html(result[0].attributes.name);
   $('.class').html(result[0].attributes.class);
   $('.like').html(result[0].attributes.like);
   $('.sport').html(result[0].attributes.sport);
 }
```

If you can use ES6 features, you just can do destructuring, and your function will be:

```js
function(result){
  const {name, class, like, sport} = result[0].attributes

  $('.name').html(name);
  $('.class').html(class);
  $('.like').html(like);
  $('.sport').html(sport);
}
```